# "Compiler Error Message: CS0434: The namespace" ... conflicts with... When deploying a .net application on IIS, got error

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, iis-7

I got this error when publishing an asp.net application to IIS 7. This is the MSDN help page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8td0be1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the namespace name to be different than the aspx class name. Specifically what was:
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Rdep.aspx.cs" Inherits="Rdep" %>

I changed to:
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="RdepApp.aspx.cs" Inherits="RdepClass" %>

I changed the file name to RdepApp.aspx and the class name referenced in RdepApp.aspx.cs to RdepClass

```
public partial class RdepClass
```

All these steps are probably not necessary, but it was successful.